# PPTP refusing to connect when client is windows

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, tcpdump, pptp

I have a PPTP server running and I can connect to it from linux. When I try from windows 7 (2 instances tested) it fails. Here's the syslog for such a conn:

```
pptpd[540]: CTRL: Client 109.xxx.158.201 control connection started
pptpd[540]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
pppd[541]: Plugin radius.so loaded.
pppd[541]: RADIUS plugin initialized.
pppd[541]: Plugin radattr.so loaded.
pppd[541]: RADATTR plugin initialized.
pppd[541]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
pppd[541]: Using interface ppp0
pppd[541]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
pptpd[540]: GRE: Bad checksum from pppd.
pppd[541]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
pppd[541]: Connection terminated.
pppd[541]: Modem hangup
pppd[541]: Exit.
pptpd[540]: GRE: read(fd=6,buffer=6075a0,len=8196) from PTY failed: status = -1 error = Input/output error, usually caused by unexpected termination of pppd, check option syntax and pppd logs
pptpd[540]: CTRL: PTY read or GRE write failed (pty,gre)=(6,7)
pptpd[540]: CTRL: Reaping child PPP[541]
pptpd[540]: CTRL: Client 109.xxx.158.201 control connection finished
```

I played with the mtu and ranged it from 900 to 1500 with no success. **My pptp options**:

```
name pptpd
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
proxyarp
nodefaultroute
lock
nobsdcomp
ms-dns 10.10.0.1
noipx
mtu 1404
mru 1404
```

Remember! Linux client connects so ports and protocols should be enabled.

`tcpdump -i eth0 port 1723 or proto 47` shows the following gist:
https://gist.github.com/ciokan/5595640
where `109.xxx.158.201` is me, the client.

No firewalls on client. Everything disabled. Im not a network admin and I can't understand jack from that tcpdump. HALP :)